# If you are log out of the guest. All the contents of your hard disk will be deleted

Tags: hard-drive

Ubuntu permit access to the hard drive in case of unavailability put. After restarting the computer, I am able to login using your username. I arrived as a guest. Unfortunately, the message was shown the exit if the guest user, all your hard drive data to be erased. Please help me.

Comment: All activity done while you're logged in as **guest** is deleted, and not your actual data.

Comment: You misunderstood. The data you created **before** you logged in as Guest will be fine. If you had old data in your hard drive, those will be fine. Only the data you created while logged in as Guest will be gone. For example, if you downloaded a song while logged in as guest, when you log out the song will be gone with the guest.

Answer (score 0):

As Mitch mentions in the comments. The Guest user account is a temporary account. Upon logout of the Guest, all of their changes to the system are removed. Also, the Guest account does not get access to sudo and several other options.